# Python interpreter path not working for resource file with PyCharm and Robot Framework Language Server-plugin

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework, pythonpath

I am trying to get following Robot Framework project structure to work with PyCharm and Robot Framework Language Server-plugin installed on Ubuntu 20.04.

**suite.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    keywords.resource

*** Test Cases ***
TC01
   Create Folder
   Remove Folder
```

**keywords.resource**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    UserKeywords.py
```

**UserKeywords.py**

```
import os

def create_folder():
    os.mkdir("/home/ubuntu/testfolder")

def remove_folder():
    os.rmdir("/home/ubuntu/testfolder")
```

Problem is that file *keywords.resource* is not found in suite.robot although I have added *resources* and *libraries* folders to python interpreter path settings in PyCharm as screenshot below shows. For *UserKeywords.py* library line in keywords.resource this error is not given at the same time though which seems a bit strange.
[image]

Also in project structure settings marked resources and libraries as sources.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

If I give relative path like below then test suite passes and error is not seen.

**suite.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../resources/keywords.resource
```

[image]
Relative path is not a problem with a small project like this but with a bigger project having lots of files it would help a lot to only give the file name without relative paths.

Any ideas which settings should be edited or additional settings that could be possibly tried?
I have restarted PyCharm after editing python interpreter path and project structure.

Comment: If you try to use ``printenv PYTHONPATH`` what is the output? Can you try to manually set the PYTHONPATH and see if it works or not?

Comment: Found a setting from Robot Framework Language Server-plugin regarding Pythonpath.

From Pycharm selected: File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks (Global) and Languages & Frameworks (Project).

These sections had a field for Pythonpath expected in JSON Array format.

Put following line to those.

["/home/ubuntu/robotprojects/resources", "/home/ubuntu/robotprojects/libraries"]

After that those red underscores disappeared in suite.robot probably indicating to library and resource included in pythonpath but still the original error remained when running suite.

Comment: printenv PYTHONPATH does not currently output anything.

Comment: Tried to manually set pythonpath as follows:
```ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/robotprojects$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/robotprojects/resources:/home/ubuntu/robotprojects/libraries```

After that printenv PYTHONPATH outputted:

```ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/robotprojects$ printenv PYTHONPATH
/home/ubuntu/robotprojects/resources:/home/ubuntu/robotprojects/libraries:/home/ubuntu/robotprojects/resources:/home/ubuntu/robotprojects/libraries```

Same problem remained when running suite.